# How to use Active Record Associations with ElasticSearch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, activemodel

I have the following models:

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Elasticsearch::Model
  include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :authentication


class Authentication < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :documents
```

I can query elastic search in my controller as follows:

```
@documents = Document.search params[:q]
```

@documents is populated correctly but I can no longer user ActiveRecord associations like so:

```
@documents.first.authentications.name
```

I get the following errors:

```
undefined method `authentication' for #<Elasticsearch::Model::Response::Result:0x007fd07929f5a8>
```

How can I make this work or is there a better way to handle this need?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a typo there while calling `@documents.first.authentications.name`. Note that you have an association `belongs_to :authentication`.

Please try `@documents.results` or `@documents.records` before calling `first`.
So try `@documents.records.first.authentications.name`.